# How to 'cut' DOM element and display it in other place?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have website, and I want to "cut" every `div#id` from `.tab-content` and add every div to every `li` only when viewport width is less than 768px.

My HTML page:

```
    <section id="menu">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <ul id="menu-nav" class="nav nav-pills text-center">
                    <li class="active"><h2><a href="#about" data-toggle="tab">About</a></h2></li>
                    <li><h2><a href="#services" data-toggle="tab">Services</a></h2></li>
                    <li><h2><a href="#contact"  data-toggle="tab">Contact</a></h2></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="about">
                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                            <p class="text-center">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis odit id praesentium, maxime, harum corporis officia laboriosam earum laudantium mollitia et quas, iure enim expedita. Nam sit, est libero obcaecati.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tab-pane" id="services">
                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                            <p class="text-center">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis odit id praesentium, maxime, harum corporis officia laboriosam earum laudantium mollitia et quas, iure enim expedita. Nam sit, est libero obcaecati.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tab-pane" id="contact">
                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                            <p class="text-center">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis odit id praesentium, maxime, harum corporis officia laboriosam earum laudantium mollitia et quas, iure enim expedita. Nam sit, est libero obcaecati.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I tried to use jquery for every div#ID, but it's not working.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
      var divAbout = $('#about').pop();
      $(divAbout).appendTo('#menu-nav li:first-of-type');
    }

  });
```

I want to have that result on mobile:

```
<li>
<h2>About</h2>
<div id="about">
...
</div>
</li>
```

And the same to other divs.

Comment: use media queries instead of jquery

Comment: you are already using Bootstrap, right? You just need to mess around with the `col-XX-#` things to do that

Comment: @MohitJain How I can do this using media queries ? I can manipulate css only, but can't change DOM.

Comment: @Robson you can hide show dom using media queries

Comment: @MohitJain Can you descripe it for me on example, becouse I don't know how in media queries I can do that without double content in html file.
PS Yes, its bootstrap :)

Comment: @cr0ss I tried to do a lot of things with it, but all aren't wroks fine.

I want to heve result:
Title
content
Title2
content2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the resize handler and do

```
var flag;
$(window).on('resize.menu', function () {
    var width = $(window).width(),
        $ul = $('#menu-nav');
    if (width < 768 && flag != 1) {
        flag = 1;
        $('#menu .tab-content .tab-pane').each(function () {
            $(this).appendTo($ul.find('li:has(a[href="#' + this.id + '"])'))
        });
    } else if (width >= 768 && flag != 2) {
        flag = 2;
        $ul.find('.tab-pane').appendTo('#menu .tab-content');
    }
}).trigger('resize.menu')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mhp5cstp/)

Comment: Works perfect. Exactly this I wanted to do. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Hope you're looking to develop a responsive web design. Instead of cutting the DOM and adding it to the `li` tag. Use `CSS3 media queries` to show and hide elements based on elements width.

But here is an approach for your question:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   if ($(window).width() < 768) {
       $(".tab-content div").each(function(index, ele) {
           var id = this.id; // about , contact
           $("li a[href='#'"+id+"]").parent().parent().append(this);
           // this will match li with a having href="#about" etc
       });
   }

});
```